# Query for profiling all columns (optionally filtered by name) on all tables/views (optionally filtered by name) in SAP HANA database

Tags: sql, vba, database, profiling

(apologies for the strange formatting -- trying to get better at it here!)

I'm looking for a recommendation on how best to accomplish the goal listed in the title, with an example of the output being something to the effect of:

| TableName | ColumnName | ProfileType | ProfileTypeCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TestTable | TestCol | NULLCOUNT | 278 |
| TestTable | TestCol | UNIQUEVALS | 71 |
| TestTable2 | TestCol2 | NULLCOUNT | 0 |
| TestTable2 | TestCol2 | UNIQUEVALS | 25 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I'd like to be able to accomplish this in one fell swoop, recognizing that this might not be doable via a single query, but believing there's a straightforward and efficient way; I'm just not familiar enough with HANA and with SQL coding to know what to aim at. (I do have HANA Studio and understand how to run queries in it.) I'd like to be able to have within the query the ability to specify additional ProfileTypes and have those applied to all tables/columns as well. One ProfileType I'd like to include would be a Top X most frequently used values (each value would be shown in the ProfileType column in the example table above with the count shown in the ProfileTypeCount column.)

I'm very open to input of the nature of "You're not thinking about this the right way! Consider this instead!"

I have been attempting some VBA coding with linked tables and passthrough queries in Access to accomplish this same result, but my ultimate aim is to make the HANA database itself be the system that does the work, as opposed to my local PC.

The logical methodology I've been trying to step through is:

- Extract full list of all tables/views/columns from the database itself (I've been using this query for that: `SELECT VIEW_NAME TableViewName, COLUMN_NAME ColumnName FROM VIEW_COLUMNS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME='SCHEMA'`)
- For every table/view (optionally filtered by name)

  - For every column (optionally filtered by name)

    - For every ProfileType (which could be a subquery, like `SELECT Count (*) NULLCOUNT from SCHEMA.TABLEVIEWNAME.COLUMNAME`)

      - Return a row like in the example table above
    - Loop
  - Loop
- Loop

Thank you for any help/direction!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's not clear what is profiletype(count), what is the semantics behind it and how it is calculated. This is not an official HANA terminology

Answer (score 0):

If using Python (the [hana-ml client](https://pypi.org/project/hana-ml/) in particular) is an option, parts of what you want to achieve are done by the [describe method](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html?highlight=describe#hana_ml.dataframe.DataFrame.describe) of the [HANA Dataframe](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html) object. It generates statistics such as

> count of rows ("count"),
>
> number of distinct values ("unique"),
>
> number of nulls ("nulls"),
>
> average ("mean"),
>
> standard deviation("std")
>
> median ("median"),
>
> minimum value ("min"),
>
> maximum value ("max"),
>
> 25% percentile when treated as continuous variable
> ("25_percent_cont"),
>
> 25% percentile when treated as discrete variable ("25_percent_disc"),
>
> 50% percentile when treated as continuous variable
> ("50_percent_cont"),
>
> 50% percentile when treated as discrete variable ("50_percent_disc"),
>
> 75% percentile when treated as continuous variable
> ("75_percent_cont"),
>
> 75% percentile when treated as discrete variable ("75_percent_disc")